# Can you put the # symbol in java?

Tags: java

```js
     char[] E = {'E', 'F', 'F#', 'G'};
  char[] A = {'A', 'A#', 'B', 'C'};
  char[] D = {'D', 'D', 'E', 'F'};
  char[] G = {'G', 'G#', 'A', 'A#'};
  char[] B = {'B', 'C', 'C#', 'D'};
  char[] e = {'E', 'F', 'F#', 'G'};
```

Just a quick question. I'm working on something for class and it involves notes on a guitar. I was curious if it is possible to have something like F sharp be printed out like this (F#). I've been searching for an answer and could not find one anywhere. No rush on an answer but I am curious if there is a way.

EDIT: Im putting them into an array but getting errors for an illegal use

Comment: Strings can contain arbitrary Unicode codepoints.

Comment: It is printed like any other string. You are probably familiar with printing "hello world.". Do you face any problem when printing `F#`?

Comment: System.out.println("F#");

Comment: You should always give it a try before asking. If it doesn't work, then you post a question with the code you used and any errors/oddities you observed

Comment: `F#` is not one character, it's two characters.  That's your problem.

Comment: ok. then its not possible in the way i was thinking. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that `'`s around something in Java means that the "something" inside is a character. A character is a single symbol, usually something you can type on the keyboard. `F` and `#` are two distinct symbols, so you cannot use `'`s around them together. Instead you must use `"`s because this makes a `String`:

```
"F#"
```

Comment: This fixed everything. Thank you. Im still new to Java so its nice when someone helps

Answer (score 1):

Like said above. 'F#' is not a char, so you either should us strings or use a secial char to use a variant to F  (see e.g. http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm)

```
char character = (char)402;
```

Not, you can try this in http://ideone.com

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    { 
        char character = (char)402;
        System.out.println("test: "+character);
    }
}
```